# Is it possible to include other backends in a Tkinter window than the Tk backends?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, highdpi, hdpi

I recently had many issues with Tkinter backends on my MacBook Pro high DPI display. The plots look blurry. It is a known issue, which unfortunately cannot be resolved unless using a different backend as far as I am concerned.

[image: Issue with Tk backend]

Are there any other backends in Matplotlib that offer Tkinter widgets?

If not, I would also appreciate a suggestion on how to fix the blur problem in the image I attached (I already tried changing the DPI, which was unsuccessful).

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

There is a DPI setting if you have not tried that part of pyplot.

```
pyplot.figure(dpi=300)
```

There is various matplotlib usages options.
It is important to note that you will want to use `matplotlib.use()` function before importing `pyplot`.

> TkAgg, Qt5Agg, Qt4Agg, and GTK3Agg

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

There is also MacOSX that should work better with Mac as that is what its designed for.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('MacOSX')
```

In order to use the `QT5Agg` or `QT4Agg` you will need to first install the QT library. This will provide python with the bindings to use the QT toolkit.

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


root = tk.Tk()
fig = plt.figure(dpi=200)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
```

Comment: Increasing DPI doesn't really affect the quality, it just scales the images. 
I would love to use the MacOS backend but the GUI crashes. I believe (but I'm not sure) that you can only use TkAgg for Tkinter GUIs.

Comment: @ManuelManUser I do not have a Mac to test on. As Mac has been known to have issues with quality of the image in matplotlib these are the only options I have seen over the years that have helped.

Comment: You can use the QT5Agg with tkinter if you install it.

Comment: @ManuelManUser give QT5Agg a shot. Make sure you install QT library first.

Comment: Does it have a dedicated Tkinter widget, which I can simply include in the GUI. As far as I am aware the FigureCanvasTkAgg is the only one having a `get_tk_widget()` method.

Comment: @ManuelManUser that I am not sure of. I have never used QT and never needed to. It is my understand that QT can be used within tkinter through matplotlib so I would at least try it since I do not have a Mac to test myself.